# How to map 2d point on grid/plane mesh to 3d point on sphere with minimal distortion?

Tags: shaders, glsl, maps, vertex-shader

I have a grid of voxels that I want to "bend" into a sphere via a vertex shader with minimal distortion. I've tried 2 approaches so far, both of which don't quite give me the desired effect.

1. First I tried the solution suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440390/deforming-plane-mesh-to-sphere) answer, but it seems to give me a very broken sphere with many faces backwards or overlapping and thus z-fighting.

[image]

2. Then I tried implementing this much simpler solution discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47508239/spherical-mapping), which looks a lot closer to what I want, but has huge amounts of distortion near the equator and also seems to cover less than half the sphere. It does not cause any backwards faces or z-fighting like the previous solution.

[image]

here's the code for both approaches:

```
#version 150

#moj_import <light.glsl>

in vec3 Position;
in vec4 Color;
in vec2 UV0;
in ivec2 UV2;
in vec3 Normal;

uniform sampler2D Sampler2;

uniform mat4 ModelViewMat;
uniform mat4 ProjMat;

uniform mat4 SceneModelViewMat;
uniform mat4 ModelViewInverseMat;
uniform vec3 CameraPosition;
uniform float Radius;
uniform vec2 MaxUV;

out float vertexDistance;
out vec4 vertexColor;
out vec2 texCoord0;
out vec4 normal;

#define PI 3.14159265359
#define TWO_PI 6.28318530718

// First solution
vec3 toSphere(float u, float v, float radius)
{
    float lon = TWO_PI * u;
    float lat = PI * v;
    float x = radius * cos(lat) * cos(lon);
    float y = radius * cos(lat) * sin(lon);
    float z = radius * sin(lat);
    return vec3(x, y, z);
}

// Second solution
vec3 toSphere1(vec3 pos)
{
    return normalize(pos) * pos.y;
}

void main()
{
    vec3 posMS = (ModelViewInverseMat * vec4(Position, 1)).xyz;

    // First solution
    // float u = posMS.x / MaxUV.x;
    // float v = posMS.z / MaxUV.y;
    // float radius = posMS.y;
    // vec4 pos = SceneModelViewMat * vec4(toSphere(u, v, radius), 1);

    // Second solution
    vec4 pos = SceneModelViewMat * vec4(toSphere1(posMS), 1);
    
    gl_Position = ProjMat * ModelViewMat * pos;

    // Unrelated
    vertexDistance = length((ModelViewMat * pos).xyz);
    vertexColor = Color * minecraft_sample_lightmap(Sampler2, UV2);
    texCoord0 = UV0;
    normal = ProjMat * ModelViewMat * vec4(Normal, 0.0);
}
```

So my question is: what is a good way to map a 2d point to a 3d point on a sphere with minimal distortion? Pretty much all I can find online is only about forward projections where a point on a sphere in transformed to a point on a map, not the other way around.

Comment: [As the list of map projections shows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections), there is no undistorted or minimally distorted way to do this. Every choice of projection has different trade-offs, distorting certain aspects more than others.

Comment: I know, but as I said, all I can find online is only how to project a sphere to a plane, and almost never the other way around. I can't figure out how to invert the various map projections myself. @DMGregory

Comment: If you have one specific map projection that you want to invert, you can post on the GIS or Mathematics StackExchange sites to ask "How can I invert [name of projection]". The trouble with the current question here is that someone who wants to answer would need to guess at what kind of distortion trade-offs are right for your game. So there's a high risk of putting a lot of time into an answer just to hear back "oh, that projection isn't good for my needs because [distortion issue]". You can help with this by identifying specific success criteria for your game's projection needs.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE. I've edited your post to remove the spoiler tags. Spoiler tags are commonly used on sites like Movies & TV, Science Fiction & Fantasy, and Puzzling to obscure movie or game spoilers (hence the name), or hints and solutions to puzzles. They didn't seem to fit the context of your post & trying to answer without referencing the images would be significantly more difficult. If you feel that the edit harms your post, you can always roll back my edit, but please include a comment as to *why* you feel spoiler tags should be used here.  Thanks & good luck with your project!